# Unicode chars convert to UTF-8 php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

I need to get this symbols in UTF-8 code format, is it possible?
Maybe not all - but just valid for UTF-8.

I tried convert information in columns: Unicode: Decimal, Unicode: Hex

But i don't know ho to do this with php.

chr() - for ANSII

UPD: I need convert it and for storing in MySQL DB utf-8 like a symbols.

Which php function will do this convert '20ac' to '€' symbol?

Comment: Just paste them in your code.

Comment: I need convert it for MySQL DB  saving

Comment: You should still paste them in your code, and make sure your database connection is configured to use utf-8.

Comment: if i passed them like they are I get not-readable symbols, except dollar sign, EURO also not readable but in UTF-8 it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Where $text it's - 20ac

```
html_entity_decode('&#x'.$text.';',ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

Also for connectionwith MySQL check utf-8 CHARACTER SET.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
$utf8 = html_entity_decode("&#x20ac;", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the utf8?  Or do you just need to store into a database table?  Simply paste `ман` into a string in PHP that you are about to store into the database.  Using bin2hex() will convert it.  Or using `SELECT HEX()` from the table will convert to utf8.  That particular currency is hex `D0BCD0B0D0BD` in utf8.

The Euro symbol is hex `E282AC` in utf8; `20AC` is the unicode hex.